# Can't catch an unhandled Promise rejection from 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm using a 3rd parth library to make an async call in my nodejs backend code. There's an unhandled promise rejection coming from this call which I'm having trouble catching. (It brings down my node app.)

Based on the input passed, it's expected to fail sometimes:

```
exports.getSomeData = (input) => {
    console.log('GETTING DATA...')
    return ThirdPartyLib.makeAsyncCall(input).then((result) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
        return result;
    },(rejection) => {
        console.log('REJECTED');
        return {};
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR');
        return {};
    });
}
```

But none of the `REJECTED`/`ERROR` messages print when it fails. I just see a console message from the lib: `Unhandled rejection at: Promise` and my app goes down.

Am I missing anything in the way I handle the non-happy path?

Is it possible for the library code to do something that the above WOULDN'T catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for the library code to do something that the above WOULDN'T catch?

Sure, it just has to create a Promise (e.g. by calling an async function) without chaining it into the promise chain (aka without `await`ing it):

```
  async makeAsyncCall(data) {
    Promise.reject("Possible");
  }
```

So yes, the library you are using should either await that detached promise or it should attach an error handler to it (and handle / purposely ignore the error). It's not your fault.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks, appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the double rejection handler (which is pointless, just use `catch()`), your code should just work.

So given that you are seeing that error, this means that the library you are using has a bug.

Comment: Ah ok, so the reject callback and the catch are redundant? Thanks for pointing that out.